# C++ Compile Error in Visual Studio 2012: LPCWSTR and wstring

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, wstring, visual-studio-2012

The following code compiles in Visual Studio 2010 but fails to compile in the Visual Studio 2012 RC.

```
#include <string>

// Windows stuffs
typedef __nullterminated const wchar_t *LPCWSTR;

class CTestObj {
public:
    CTestObj() {m_tmp = L"default";};

    operator LPCWSTR()  { return m_tmp.c_str(); }       // returns const wchar_t*
    operator std::wstring() const { return m_tmp; }     // returns std::wstring

protected:
    std::wstring m_tmp;
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CTestObj x;
    std::wstring strval = (std::wstring) x;

    return 0;
}
```

The error returned is:

> error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from `'CTestObj'` to `'std::wstring'`
>   No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

I've already realized that commenting out either of the conversion operators fixes the compile problem. I just want to understand:

1. *What*'s going on under the hood to cause this
2. *Why* this compiles in VS2010 and not in VS2012? Is it because of a C++11 change?

Comment: Uh, most likely it's a bug...

Comment: That might be the case but my hunch is it is a breaking change that I just don't understand.

Comment: Having `operator LPCWSTR` is probably a bad idea anyway.  If you have a function `CTestObj foo()`, then the operator would silently allow `LPCWSTR x = foo();`, and you now have a pointer to freed memory.

Comment: @jamesdlin, it's a convention that has worked well for Microsoft's CString for many years. The theoretical problems are far outweighed by the everyday convenience.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I wouldn't agree with "worked well".  IMO it's a convention that's been problematic with `CString` (and `_bstr_t`) for many years.  IMO the additional burden of explicitly invoking a `c_str()` method is very low, and the C++ standards committee did go the `c_str` route instead of the implicit cast route for a reason.  (Although now with C++11, an *explicit* cast operator seems like a fine compromise.)

Comment: You can simplify this repro a little by removing the assignment. just use "((std::wstring) x);".  Cast it and throw away the result.  There is ambiguity IF and Only if it were implied.  Since you are EXPLICITLY casting, there should be no ambiguity.  Please file a bug with MS: you can do this from the help menu in VS2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the logic under the hood, the operator overload is trying to copy the code and the object every time you cast. Therefore, you need to [return it as a reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/74a-returning-values-by-value-reference-and-address/) instead of attempting to return a new object based on the field. The line:

```
operator std::wstring() const { return m_tmp; }
```

should be:

```
operator std::wstring&() { return m_tmp; }
```

The following compiles and runs as expected.

```
#include <string>

// Windows stuffs
typedef __nullterminated const wchar_t *LPCWSTR;

class CTestObj {
public:
    CTestObj() {m_tmp = L"default";};

    operator LPCWSTR()  { return m_tmp.c_str(); }       // returns const wchar_t*
    operator std::wstring&() { return m_tmp; }     // returns std::wstring

protected:
    std::wstring m_tmp;
};


int main()
{
    CTestObj x;
    std::wstring strval = (std::wstring) x;
    wprintf(L"%s\n", strval.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should have been answered a long time ago. My sympathies for such a long wait-time!

Comment: And I'm sorry for taking so long to accept this answer! Thank you so much.